# Make parameter variable usable to setState in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to get the value of `latitude` and `longitude` variables, so that I can pass them to the `fetchAlbum()` function inside `initstate()`.

```
class MainContent extends StatefulWidget {
  final double latitude;
  final double longitude;

  MainContent({Key key, @required this.latitude, @required this.longitude}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainContentState createState() => _MainContentState();
}

class _MainContentState extends State<MainContent> {
  bool isLoading = false;

  Future<Album> futureAlbum;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    var a = 23.2599; // update the value of 'a' by using 'latitude' variable
    var b = 77.4126; // update the value of 'a' by using 'longitude' variable
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum(a, b);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
var a = widget.latitude;
var b = widget.longitude;
```